# can you help me to do a difference of CDF?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, cumulative-distribution-function

I have 2 CDF's with equal number of points that I want to compare. These are from:

- Temperature of 1 month from 2012
- Mean temperature across months

What can I do to obtain this difference, this is from the formula of Finkelstein-Schafer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't heard of FS distance that you mentioned. It just seems like mean of distance of corresponding points. I just looked it up and see that the only mention of this method is in generating Typical Meteorological Year (maybe because of some paper?).

If you want to compare these 2 CDF's a more standard way would be Kullback–Leibler divergence. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Another alternative is KS Test [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

If your objective is not to measure distance of CDF's but in fact 'predict' a typical meteorological year/month, then that answer would differ.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit, you understand perfecty , well yeah is a distance, like i have differentes values but the same amount of data, so i want to choose the month with respect to closeness of the month to the long-term mean and median.

Comment: yes ! the alternative is KS Test ! So thank you so much, have an excellent day

Comment: Original reference for FS is "Improved goodness-of-fit tests" by JM Finkelstein and RE Schafer, Biometrika, v58 n3 p641, 1971.